# Rails JSON Serialization of Decimal adds Quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the default JSON serialization for a model that has a number of decimal and integer attributes. An example result is:

```
{ "user": { "id": 1234, "rating": "98.7" } }
```

Notice the addition of quotes around the value of "rating". This causes the deserialization library I'm using to incorrectly treat these as strings (instead of decimals). Can Rails be set to not use the quotes for all decimals?

**Edit:**

I'm on Rails 3.0.7 and Ruby 1.9.2 if that makes a difference.

**Edit:**

Terminal:

```
rails g model user rating:decimal
rake db:migrate
```

Console:

```
user = User.create(rating: 98.7)
user.to_json
```

Comment: Please include some additional code. I was unable to reproduce this.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The only "safe" way to hand decimals from language A to language B is to use a String. If your json contains `"rating": 98.79999999999999` it will probably be converted to `98.79999999999998` by your JavaScript runtime.

See [BigDecimal as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/BigDecimal.html#method-i-as_json) documentation:

> A BigDecimal would be naturally
>   represented as a JSON number. Most
>   libraries, however, parse non-integer
>   JSON numbers directly as floats.
>   Clients using those libraries would
>   get in general a wrong number and no
>   way to recover other than manually
>   inspecting the string with the JSON
>   code itself.
>
> That’s why a JSON string is returned.
>   The JSON literal is not numeric, but
>   if the other end knows by contract
>   that the data is supposed to be a
>   BigDecimal, it still has the chance to
>   post-process the string and get the
>   real value.

If you want to force Rails not to quote these, you could monkey-patch BigDecimal (see Rails [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb)).

```
# not needed: to compare with the Numeric implementation
class Numeric
  def as_json(options = nil) self end #:nodoc:
  def encode_json(encoder) to_s end #:nodoc:
end

class BigDecimal
  def as_json(options = nil) self end
  def encode_json(encoder) to_s end #:nodoc:
end
```

Comment: Thanks Marcel. Should I not be using 'decimal' type for storage of currencies and volumes? I don't think I'll ever hit any serious rounding errors.

Comment: In theory you should. But I would prefer integers over decimals (the `money` gem uses integers in a `xyz_cents` column) for most real-world problems regarding currencies.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Rails 7, it still gets serialized as a string.

Answer (score 29):

This has changed for Rails 4.0 which has the option `ActiveSupport.encode_big_decimal_as_string` so that you can specify your BigDecimal serialization preference. [See issue 6033](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6033)

In the meantime, if you're comfortable with the arguments put forward in 6033 and you're running a Rails version lower than 4.0 you can monkey patch BigDecimal as below

```
require 'bigdecimal'

class BigDecimal
  def as_json(options = nil) #:nodoc:
    if finite?
      self
    else
      NilClass::AS_JSON
    end
  end
end
```

This solved my issues with RABL pumping out strings for dollar amounts stored as BigDecimal.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I haven't looked at this issue in a bit but it is good to know it can be customized in 4.0

Comment: No problem. Just thought I'd put this solution out there for others doing the rounds on Google!

Comment: Unfortunately the `encode_big_decimal_as_string` option has been deprecated again in Rails 4.1.

Comment: Aparently you can use `activesupport-json_encoder` gem to restore it

Comment: making breaking changes is a great idea <\sarcasm>

Comment: @Tilo I don't understand the intention of your sarcasm. Breaking changes happen all the time. Your tests should confirm that your app conforms to it's requirements.

Comment: sorry for the sarcasm, but I wasn't exactly happy to waste precious time on figuring out why decimals are encoded as strings. When those minutes are multiplied by a large number of Rails users, maybe that's a good reason for not doing breaking changes like this.  You build model rockets? Cool!!

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you meant my solution was a breaking change :) Yes, I'm not sure what the thoughts are on this from the Rails team. Technically valid for share trading apps where fractions matter, not so helpful for the more common use-case of product prices!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, didn't work for me as is. Added `self.to_f` instead of `self` - this worker ok.

Answer (score 10):

if you are using ActiveModel::Serializer you can also use to_f to force the conversion from Decimal to Float type. that wil also trim out the quote for you!

so in your object serializer class. do

```
def rating
  self.rating.to_f
end
```

Comment: Doesn't this completely ruin the point of using BigDecimal in the first place, though? If I'm trying to pass a monetary value to an API endpoint, for example, this approach will re-introduce all of the rounding errors inherent to Floats. If it mutilates the data, it shouldn't be considered a solution.

Comment: This causes "SystemStackError (stack level too deep)" exception for me. Using object.rating.to_f works fine.

Answer (score 0):

With Rails 5 encode_big_decimal_as_string doesn't work (it was deprecated so no surprise there).

If you add jbuilder to your application

```
# Gemfile
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
```

Then just create a json view that casts the decimal to a float just for the view, you should be golden.

```
# app/views/yourmodel/index.json.jbuilder
json.array! @yourmodels do |yourmodel|
  json.attributethatisadecimal yourmodel.attributethatisadecimal.to_f
end
```

This worked well for me - a bit more work (because you have to map your model to jbuilder) but this approach seems pretty clean.

Comment: Doesn't work for me because .to_f loses all the accuracy that I gained by using BigDecimal in the first place.