# Django JSONField encoding floating point values as strings?

Tags: django, json

I'm saving the following simple, valid JSON object to a model in my Django app:

```
{
    "start_date": 1311471044.24338
    "post_count": 25
}
```

The model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import json as json

class UserProfile(models.Model):
   data = json.JSONField()
```

To read the posted data, I basically do

```
posted_data = request.FILES.get('posted_data').read()
json_data = simplejson.loads(posted_data)
```

The data then contains the expect type (float)

```
logging.debug( "start_date type: " + str(type(json_data.get('start_date'))))
logging.debug( "post_count type: " + str(type(json_data.get('post_count'))))

>> 2011-07-24 10:03:01,636 DEBUG start_date type: <type 'float'>
>> 2011-07-24 10:03:01,636 DEBUG post_count type: <type 'int'>
```

I then save the data like this:

```
user_profile.data = json_data
user_profile.save()
```

and then I read the data back, integers are fine, but floating point numbers are quoted, for example:

```
print user_profile.data

{
    "post_count : 25
    "start_date": "1311471044.24338"
}
```

How can I prevent floating point numbers from being turned to strings unnecessarily?

**Edit:**

May have found an explanation here: [Rails JSON Serialization of Decimal adds Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128794/rails-json-serialization-of-decimal-adds-quotes)

I still would be interested in other explanations though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128794/rails-json-serialization-of-decimal-adds-quotes/6132054#6132054) seems to be the best explanation:

> The only "safe" way to hand decimals from language A to language B is to use a String. If your json contains "rating": 98.79999999999999 it will probably be converted to 98.79999999999998 by your JavaScript runtime.

Comment: you could also break the integral part and the fractional part into two integer fields.

Comment: Breaking numbers into two integer fields makes API ugly and usually never done in normal production systems.