# rails : rabl gem, customize type conversion

Tags: ruby, type-conversion, rabl

I use Mongo DB with Mongoid but same thing appear with Mongo Mapper.

I get the following output :

```
{
  :a_doc => {
    :id => BSON::ObjectId('4f8d37521e5945f14a0000a3')
  }
}
```

I would like to keep this clean syntaxe :

```
object @a_doc
attributes :id
```

Instead to do write :

```
object @a_doc
attributes :string_id => :id
```

So at some point in rabl, I would like to catch type to convert it.
Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with how rabl and it's JSON backing libraries convert objects to JSON. [Folks have reported similar issues with Decimal and timestamp](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/188) formats. The library is probably not doing the conversion correctly

You can provide an attribute reader as [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765688/2284646) suggests, something like

```
# doc.rb
def api_id
  id.to_s
end
```

Then your rabl view:

```
# doc.rabl
object @a_doc
attributes :api_id
```

Comment: Woo, it's been a long time... Now I use to use _id attribute. It behaves like your solution, but without having to add a method in every models ;)