# rails to_json quoting decimal values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

(**update**)
An array of geocoordinates, **built from a collection of records**

```
[{"point_lon"=>0.1307336132e3, "point_lat"=>-0.252978933e2, "title"=>"kata tjuta"}, 
{"point_lon"=>0.154984876e3, "point_lat"=>-0.17e2, "title"=>"error case"}, 
{"point_lon"=>0.1310369614747e3, "point_lat"=>-0.253455545e2, "title"=>"uluru"}]
```

has proper quoting structure, but for JSON input to a javascript needs the rockets to be replaced by a colon.

Transforming the array via [JSON.generate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) or `to_json` unfortunately leads to quoting of the decimal values and being ignored by the javascript

```
[{"point_lon":"130.7336132","point_lat":"-25.2978933","point_name":"kata tjuta"},
{"point_lon":"154.984876","point_lat":"-17.0","point_name":"error case"},
{"point_lon":"131.0369614747","point_lat":"-25.3455545","point_name":"uluru"}]
```

How can this array be transformed without quoting decimals?

Comment: Can't reproduce on `rails 5.1.6`, When I do `puts a.to_json` I get
`[{"point_lon":130.7336132,"point_lat":-25.2978933,"title":"kata tjuta"},{"point_lon":154.984876,"point_lat":-17.0,"title":"error case"},{"point_lon":131.0369614747,"point_lat":-25.3455545,"title":"uluru"}]`

Comment: Good point. I get the same result if I state the array as `a`... however that array is a collection `@points` and that collection to_json gets quoted.

Comment: That's strange, it should work for collections too. Perhaps the fields don't have correct data type? Could you add the definition of the table from `schema.rb`?

Comment: @user000001 yes, data types are decimal, with `, precision: 15, scale: 10` @Sebastian Palma same quoted output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use `decimal` numbers instead of `float`, so rails quotes the strings to preserve the precision. You can find methods to avoid this in this related question: [Rails JSON Serialization of Decimal adds Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128794/rails-json-serialization-of-decimal-adds-quotes)